# Bit packing return values

Tags: solidity

Setting variables like this can pack them into a single slot:

```
uint128 v1 =1;
uint128 v2 =2;
```

But does return values also pack in this way? Does

```
returns (uint128, uint128)
```

also pack data?

Will experiment it later myself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Setting variables like this can pack them into a single slot

Your example doesn't work, `uint` is an alias for `uint256`, so in that specific example both variable use a full slot each. Maybe it was a typo and you meant `uint128` ?

> But does return values also pack in this way ?

No. Input and outputs are abi encoded (see the [documentation](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.13/abi-spec.html#argument-encoding)), that is, padded to 32 bytes each with some caveats for dynamic types. Thus, the following function would return two 32 bytes values :

```
function test() public view returns (uint128, uint128) {
  uint128 a = 1;
  uint128 b = 2;

  return (a, b);
}
```

I hope that answers your question.